# Question regarding convexity in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question:

Let p be a sublinear functional on a normed vector spaceX. Fix β >0, and show that the set C:={x∈X ∣∣ p(x)≤β} is convex.

I do not really know how to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $p(ax+by) \leq ap(x)+bp(y);$ if $a + b \leq 1,$ then the right-hand side is $\leq \beta.$ Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Yes, but all attempts failed. Thanks, I understand the inequality, but how do we know that the right hand side is ≤β if a+b≤1 ?